# YARN shell commands to get top 3 yarn application in running state

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to get top 3 yarn applications in running state from **all clusters**
output : AppicationId, Application Type, Memory occupied, start time

Comment: `yarn application -list | head -3`??

Comment: does it fetch details for different cluster as well ? you are logged in to some machine in different cluster and you want to fetch details from different cluster ?

Comment: These details are fetched from the Resource Manager. A machine outside the cluster can't fetch details for that cluster.

Comment: we can use resource manager rest api ?